# SwiftUI How can I add an activity indicator in WKWebView?

Tags: swiftui, wkwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

How can I add an activity indicator in WKWebView which will display the indicator while the webpage is loading and disappears when loaded ?

I've looked at some of the old posts but could not figure out how to do it in SwiftUI
see link to one of the old solutions below
[How to add Activity Indicator to WKWebView (Swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819656/how-to-add-activity-indicator-to-wkwebview-swift-3)

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496638/activity-indicator-in-swiftui. UIActivityIndicator is not yet a native view in SwiftUI so you may want to convert it to one and then add it to your view.

Comment: @palme How do I turn off the activity indicator once the WKWebview has finished loading?

Comment: The WKWebView has a a navigationDelegate which calls 
`func webView(WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!)` once it is done loading. In there you can use `stopAnimating()` of the `UIActivityIndicator `.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `UIViewRepresentable` to create a [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityindicatorview):

> You control when an activity indicator animates by calling the `startAnimating()` and `stopAnimating()` methods. To automatically hide the activity indicator when animation stops, set the `hidesWhenStopped` property to true.
>
> You can set the color of the activity indicator by using the `color` property.

```
struct ActivityIndicatorView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicatorView>) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicatorView>) {
        isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Create a `LoadingView` to allow you to wrap around your views:

*This allows you to style the activity views content.*

```
struct LoadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                self.content()
                    .disabled(self.isShowing)
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Loading...")
                    ActivityIndicatorView(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2, height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                .background(Color.secondary.colorInvert())
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to update the `LoadingView(...)` status you'll need to introduce a view model that inherits from `ObservableObject`:

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58825642/264802

```
class WebViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var url: String
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    
    init (url: String) {
        self.url = url
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: WebViewModel
    let webView = WKWebView()

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self.viewModel)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        private var viewModel: WebViewModel
        
        init(_ viewModel: WebViewModel) {
            self.viewModel = viewModel
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.viewModel.isLoading = false
        }
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) { }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        if let url = URL(string: self.viewModel.url) {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }

        return self.webView
    }
}
```

Then to use it inside your views you would do the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = WebViewModel(url: "http://www.google.com")

    var body: some View {
        LoadingView(isShowing: self.$model.isLoading) {
            WebView(viewModel: self.model)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I turn off the activity indicator once the WKWebview has finished loading?

Comment: @AshleyVaz I updated my answer to show you how to turn off the activity indicator once the `WKWebview` has finished loading.

Comment: @AshleyVaz Did this answer your questions?

Comment: Thanks very much appreciate it, yes this helped.

Answer (score -1):

**Using 3 Steps I do it in my project.**

**Step 1: Create a Loading View**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ActivityIndicatorView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: Context) {
        isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
    }
}

// Main View
struct LoadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    let message: String
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                self.content()
                    .disabled(self.isShowing)
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)

                VStack {
                    Text(self.message)
                        .bold()
                    ActivityIndicatorView(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                .background(Color.secondary.colorInvert())
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }

}

// Mark: Testing

struct LoadingIndicator: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoadingView(isShowing: .constant(true), message: "Loading...") {
            NavigationView {
                List(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], id: \.self) { row in
                    Text(row)
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("A List"), displayMode: .large)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ActivityIndicatorView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoadingIndicator()
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Create a WebView and WebViewModel**

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

class WebViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var webViewModel: WebViewModel
    let urlString: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let wkWebView = WKWebView()
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            wkWebView.load(urlRequest)
        }
        return wkWebView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ wkWebView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        // do nothing
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        let webViewModel: WebViewModel

        init(_ webViewModel: WebViewModel) {
            self.webViewModel = webViewModel
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            webViewModel.isLoading = true
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            webViewModel.isLoading = false
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> WebView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(webViewModel)
    }
}

struct WebView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WebView(webViewModel: WebViewModel(),
                urlString: "https://instagram.com/mahmudahsan/")
    }
}
```

**Step 3: In your main view use the following code to show indicator and webview**

```
ZStack {
        WebView(webViewModel: webViewModel, urlString: "http://ithinkdiff.net")
            .frame(height: 1000)

        if webViewModel.isLoading {
              LoadingView(isShowing: .constant(true), message: "Loading...") {
                            EmptyView()
              }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahmud Ahsan, the view loads the webpage but continues to display the activity indicator after the page is fully loaded, any ideas ?

Comment: I added a break point on the coordinator class, it seems the flow of control never reaches the         `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.webViewModel.isLoading = false
        }` in the coordinator.